# jQuery(document).on ('focus')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Whenever the user focuses on clicks on an input, I want to trigger a method. 
I have the following code:

```
jQuery(document).on('focus click', function(e){
        console.log("focused on " + $(e.target).attr('id'));
});
```

But whenever I focus on an element it just gives `focused on undefined`. What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 7):

You missed the input selector in bind event using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
jQuery(document).on('focus click', 'input',  function(e){
        console.log("focused on " + $(e.target).attr('id'));
});
```

> *syntax of on()* .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) ), [reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
$(document).on('focus click', 'input',  function(e){
        console.log("focused on " + e.target.id);
});
```

Also just `e.target.id` is enough..

Comment: Even `this.id` suffices ;).